# Effective Sample Size for a cycle or mixture of kernels

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, measure-theory

The Effective Sample Size (ESS) of a univariate Markov Chain can be used to assess it performance.

Is there a version of the ESS for when the Markov Kernel is a mixture $\alpha K_1 + (1-\alpha) K_2$ or a cycle $K_2 K_1$ of kernels?

I suppose there might be different versions based upon whether $K_1$ and $K_2$ leave $\pi$ invariant or not.

Comment: Not really since the ESS is based on the autocorrelations of the Markov chain.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for the comment. What would you say is the recommended way to proceed? In the case of a cycle of kernels $K = K_2 K_1$ I was thinking of computing the ESS only on samples from each kernel respectively. That is, computing the ESS for $K_1$ using all odd-indexed samples and the ESS for $K_2$ using all even-indexed samples. If this is not recommended, then what is a good way to assess the performance of such algorithm? There must be a way because the Gibbs sampler is a cycle of kernels too